# how to parse xml for specific element in swift

Tags: swift, nsxmlparser

I would like to parse student schedule only for the student "Karly". Task here means - classes. So I need to go to student-info first, and find out a student whose name is "Karly" and then parse task for her.
Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<students-scheule-information>
    <student-schedule>
        <student-info>
            <name>Jiyoon Lee</name>
            <phone>765-637-8532</phone>
            <uniqueID>S201501</uniqueID>
        </student-info>
        <week-schedule>
            <task>
                <notificationID>notification1_1</notificationID>
                <date>20151112</date>
                <starttime>1200</starttime>
                <endtime>1305</endtime>
                <location>knoy376</location>
                <title>Math</title>
                <comments>good</comments>
                <image>X</image>
                <ischeckable>true</ischeckable>
                <repeatnum>3</repeatnum>
                <repeatinterval>5</repeatinterval>
            </task>
            <task>
                <notificationID>notification1_2</notificationID>
                <date>20151111</date>
                <starttime>1200</starttime>
                <endtime>1305</endtime>
                <location>knoy376</location>
                <title>History</title>
                <comments>good</comments>
                <image>X</image>
                <ischeckable>true</ischeckable>
                <repeatnum>3</repeatnum>
                <repeatinterval>5</repeatinterval>
            </task>
            <task>
                <notificationID>notification1_3</notificationID>
                <date>20151113</date>
                <starttime>0930</starttime>
                <endtime>1200</endtime>
                <location>knoy376</location>
                <title>Geography</title>
                <comments>good</comments>
                <image>X</image>
                <ischeckable>true</ischeckable>
                <repeatnum>3</repeatnum>
                <repeatinterval>5</repeatinterval>
            </task>
            <task>
                <notificationID>notification1_4</notificationID>
                <date>20151109</date>
                <starttime>1200</starttime>
                <endtime>1735</endtime>
                <location>knoy376</location>
                <title>Art</title>
                <comments>good</comments>
                <image>X</image>
                <ischeckable>true</ischeckable>
                <repeatnum>3</repeatnum>
                <repeatinterval>5</repeatinterval>
            </task>
            <task>
                <notificationID>notification1_5</notificationID>
                <date>20151109</date>
                <starttime>2000</starttime>
                <endtime>2100</endtime>
                <location>knoy376</location>
                <title>Intermediate German</title>
                <comments>good</comments>
                <image>X</image>
                <ischeckable>true</ischeckable>
                <repeatnum>3</repeatnum>
                <repeatinterval>5</repeatinterval>
            </task>
        </week-schedule>
    </student-schedule>
    <student-schedule>
        <student-info>
            <name>Karly</name>
            <phone>765-637-8222</phone>
            <uniqueID>S201502</uniqueID>
        </student-info>
        <week-schedule>
            <task>
                <notificationID>notification3</notificationID>
                <date>20151109</date>
                <starttime>2210</starttime>
                <endtime>2305</endtime>
                <location>knoy376</location>
                <title>Chemisrty</title>
                <comments>Cool</comments>
                <image>X</image>
                <ischeckable>true</ischeckable>
                <repeatnum>3</repeatnum>
                <repeatinterval>5</repeatinterval>
            </task>
            <task>
                <notificationID>notification1_5</notificationID>
                <date>20151109</date>
                <starttime>2000</starttime>
                <endtime>2100</endtime>
                <location>knoy376</location>
                <title>History</title>
                <comments>good</comments>
                <image>X</image>
                <ischeckable>true</ischeckable>
                <repeatnum>3</repeatnum>
                <repeatinterval>5</repeatinterval>
            </task>
            <task>
                <notificationID>notification1_5</notificationID>
                <date>20151112</date>
                <starttime>2000</starttime>
                <endtime>2100</endtime>
                <location>knoy376</location>
                <title>Math</title>
                <comments>good</comments>
                <image>X</image>
                <ischeckable>true</ischeckable>
                <repeatnum>3</repeatnum>
                <repeatinterval>5</repeatinterval>
            </task>
            <task>
                <notificationID>notification1_5</notificationID>
                <date>20151111</date>
                <starttime>1130</starttime>
                <endtime>1420</endtime>
                <location>knoy376</location>
                <title>Biology</title>
                <comments>good</comments>
                <image>X</image>
                <ischeckable>true</ischeckable>
                <repeatnum>3</repeatnum>
                <repeatinterval>5</repeatinterval>
            </task>
            <task>
                <notificationID>notification1_5</notificationID>
                <date>20151113</date>
                <starttime>1000</starttime>
                <endtime>1300</endtime>
                <location>knoy376</location>
                <title>Geography</title>
                <comments>good</comments>
                <image>X</image>
                <ischeckable>true</ischeckable>
                <repeatnum>3</repeatnum>
                <repeatinterval>5</repeatinterval>
            </task>
        </week-schedule>
    </student-schedule>
</students-scheule-information>
```

I also have this code here for NSXMLParser which shows all  for both students:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    anElement = elementName
        if elementName == "task" {
                title = String()
            }

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    let data = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
  if (!data.isEmpty) {
    switch anElement {
        case "title":
        aTitle = data
        case "starttime":
        aStartTime = data
        case "endtime":
        anEndTime = data
        case "location":
        aLocation = data
    default:
        print("Check your file")
    }


   }
}


func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "task" {
        let oneClass: TheClass = TheClass()
        oneClass.title = aTitle
        oneClass.location = aLocation
        oneClass.startTime = aStartTime
        oneClass.endTime = anEndTime
        oneClass.classColor = aClassColor
        classList.append(oneClass)

    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I would like to parse tasks only for the student "Karly".

Comment: Well, that's not going to happen, because you have no parser for the `<student-info>`. Your parser is for the `<task>` only.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am trying to change that, that's why I posted the question :)

Comment: But no one is going to write your code for you. And your question is too vague to be answered in any other way. I can suggest to you the _strategy_ that I would use (and I have done so). But this is not a "write my code for free" service.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to write a parser for a specialized search task. It's better, if possible, to parse the *whole* XML and work with the results. Your XML is extremely simple, and can easily be parsed into Swift objects.

So what I would do is write your parser to read the *entire XML* and create an array of `student` objects, where each `student` object has a `name` property, a `phone` property, a `uniqueID` property, and a `tasks` property. The `tasks` property would be an array of `task` objects, where each `task` has properties corresponding to the subelements of the `<task>` element.

Now you've got a Swift array, so it will be trivial to find the `student` whose `name` is `"Karly"` and consult that student's tasks. The XML will be gone; you'll be working entirely with Swift objects, and can proceed to do anything you want with the data.